# puedo cargar una funcion js en body<body ?>

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito saber una como llamar funciones js  porque no se como se hace   pero que sea diferente a onchange ni onclick. La única documentación que he encontrado ha sido para sin respuesta a mi pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es posible, utilizando el evento `onload`, este se ejecutara al terminar de cargar la pagina, ejemplo:

```js
function My_onLoad() {
 alert("Hola mundo!!");
}
```

```html
<body onload="My_onLoad()">
</body>
```

Quedo atento a tus comentarios o inquietudes, Saludos!! ;))

Comment: ok voy a probarlo porque necesito que cada vez que se refresque la pagina necesito que haga primero la funcion js.

Answer (score 1):

Para cargar la función a la hora de cargar la página solo tienes que usar el método **onload**  de javascrpt te dejo el ejemplo:

```js
function holamundo(){
 console.log("Hola Mundo");
}
```

```html
<body onload="holamundo()">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternativamente a las respuestas dadas, puedes usar una etiqueta `<script>` antes de cerrar el `</body>`.

```
<body>
   Aquí va tu contenido html y luego de eso un elemento script. 

   <script>
     // este es un bloque de código que se ejecuta después de que se 
     // cargo todo el documento. 

     alert('hola mundo');

   </script>
   <!-- la idea es no agregar mas elementos aquí -->    
</body>
```